# Project raster tool stays white at iteration in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, modelbuilder, wgs84

I want to project a bunch of rasters (WGS84) to different UTM (WGS84) coordinate systems. The coordinate system depends on a field value of a point shape.

So on each raster lays a point with its spatial reference.

I scripted a little ModelBuilder toolchain for it but unfortunately the Project raster Tool stays white and doesn't execute.

[image]

**Some detail information for the toolchain:**

I extract the information wich point lays on the individual raster with the sample tool. Then I get for each raster a table with many no data points and one with the stored EPSG Information. This point is extracted by the table select tool and then I get the EPSG with the get field value tool and store it as spatial reference.

The spatial reference I use as Output coordinate system.
**But the Project raster tool requires the "optional" Geographic Transformation although both coordinate systems use the WGS84 referece.**

[image]
[image: Tool Dialog of Create spatial reference]

- I tested the toolchain until the projection part and there is no error.
- I've checked if the rasters lay in the UTM zone I want to project them to.
- When I run the tool first, then disconnect the spatial reference and the Projection and then reconnect, the tool gets colorful. But when I run the toolchain again (without validation) only one Raster is projected several times to the same coordinate system until I cancel it.
- at no point any error message occurs when running the tool
- I've changed the data type of the field value to "Coordinate System" with no effect

Comment: What does the tool dialog of Project Raster currently look like?  I suspect it will be missing at least one parameter value.

Comment: @PolyGeo I've added a screenshot. The message box says "Undefined geographic transformation."

Comment: It says it's optional, but it seems to be complaining that its not present, so as a test try using any value from the pulldown.

Comment: @PolyGeo When I choose any value the tool turns colorful. But I can't find a WGS84 to WGS84 transformation.

Comment: You won't find a transformation from one datum to the same datum.  What coordinate system is defined for your raster, and by your Create Spatial Reference tool?  Are you sure that you need Create Spatial Reference rather than Define Projection?

Comment: @PolyGeo My rasters are in WGS84 and I need to project them to different WGS84_UTM Zones depending on their location in the world. The coordinate system is correct, so the define Projection tool would be inappropiate.

Comment: Is there any solution? If needed could I replace the Projection tool with a ArcPy script? @PolyGeo

Comment: What does the tool dialog of Create Spatial Reference look like?  Does a test model with the iterator removed work?

Comment: @PolyGeo I've added a screenshot of the tool dialog. Unfortulately nothing changes when I remove the iterator and set only on raster as Projection Input.

Comment: Try setting Create Spatial Reference as a precondition to Project Raster. I have provided you with arcpy Code in one of your previous duplicates of this question.

Comment: In that case take the Iterator out of the model that you are presenting here.  The simpler you can make your test model (while it still shows the problem) the more likely it is that one of our volunteers may be able to find the time to test.

Comment: @BERA Sorry for asking that many questions (2) with a projection theme. I'm working on a complex task and want to find different solutions and learn somthing for myself (I'm a bachelor student of geosciences) So the former questions had another main focus. And the way this toolchain works is comletely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like an Error of the Project Raster tool itself.
When I use the ArcPy script of the [Esri page](https://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/project-raster.htm) and change it a bit to insert the parameters and load this script tool to my model it works perfectly.
No error message and no white tool.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

Input_Raster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Output_Raster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Output_Coord = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(Input_Raster, Output_Raster,Output_Coord, "BILINEAR")
```